# Make WAR classes visible on EAR

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, war, ear

Greets,

Is there anyway to make the classes of a WAR available on the classpath of EAR archives, or on another WAR archives, without having to create a jar file with those WAR classes?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this via MANIFEST.MF entry 'Class-Path' in modules where you want to use classes from WAR. Or you can use vendor-dependent way(e.g. jboss 7 has modules-isolation parameter in deployment description jboss-deployment-structure.xml).

IMHO instead of exposing WAR classses to other modules, you should create JAR with common libraries, otherwise you will have really tight coupled modules in your deployment.